# How do I query a Flask SQLite database with SQLAlchemy outside of the Flask app url endpoints?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm creating a Flask REST API. It's working well as an API. I've had a growing need to connect to the app's sqlite database on the side for scheduled tasks (which [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810461/how-to-perform-periodic-task-with-flask-in-python) could address), yet also for other background IoT-triggered logs via MQTT messages.

So far, when I attempt to import ORM models created for use in the Flask app, I get this error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

This makes sense as the models are extending Flask's database [session?, something?]. Here's a scheduled task example I'm starting with where I tried to recreate the Flask app environment to make use of the model and run the task (maybe I don't need the full flask app here to use the model?):

remove_old_tokens.py

```py
#  I was going to import model here, yet that generates error.
# from ..models import TokenBlocklist

from flask import Flask
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# TODO: Not sure I like this added globally, yet maybe useful to bring in from
# another file for these types of tasks.
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' \
    + os.path.abspath('../../instance/db.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.app_context().push()
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.create_all()


# Tokens are set to expire at max 30 days. After about that long with padding,
# remove the tokens from the database to keep that table clean.
def remove_old_tokens():
    #  This line generates the same error as just importing at top of the file
    from ..models import TokenBlocklist

    forty_days = timedelta(days=40)
    forty_days_ago = datetime.now() - forty_days
    query = TokenBlocklist.__table__.delete() \
        .where(TokenBlocklist.created < forty_days_ago)
    db.session.execute(query)
    db.session.commit()
    print('old tokens deleted')


remove_old_tokens()
```

models.py

```
import uuid
from .app import db


def uuid_str():
    return str(uuid.uuid4())



class TokenBlocklist(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(
        db.String(36),
        primary_key=True,
        nullable=False,
        index=True,
        default=uuid_str
    )
    jti = db.Column(
        db.String(36),
        nullable=False,
        index=True
    )
    type = db.Column(
        db.String(10),
        nullable=False
    )
    created_at = db.Column(
        db.DateTime,
        nullable=False,
        server_default=func.now(),
        index=True
    )
```

app.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

structure

```
app/
    app.py
    models.py
    scheduled_tasks/
        remove_old_tokens.py
instance/
    db.sqlite
```

One alternative I could find was to write simple text queries, ignoring the model (finding good examples [here](https://www.gormanalysis.com/blog/intro-to-sqlalchemy/)). However, that may eventually break if I move away from SQLite when the app grows.

How do I resolve the error? Keep in mind that I'm doing more than scheduled tasks that could use a URL when working with the database (live IoT logs the UI will make use of for example).

Full code (excluding this example being worked out) is available [here](https://github.com/PikesPeakMakerspace/TeslaCore).

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @michael-butscher's comment, I was able to resolve the Import error with an altered script that makes use of absolute imports. However, now I'm running into a circular import error. I wonder if it makes sense to rework the models file, or simply query another way:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'TokenBlocklist' from partially initialized module 'app.models' (most likely due to a circular import) (/full-path-here/app/models.py)
```

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../../'))

from flask import Flask
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.abspath('../../instance/db.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

#  This may be the issue, because models.py is trying to load db from un-initialized app.py...
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.app_context().push()

#  app.models is going to try `from .app import db` hmmm...
from app.models import TokenBlocklist
db.create_all()


def remove_old_tokens():
    forty_days = timedelta(days=40)
    forty_days_ago = datetime.now() - forty_days
    query = TokenBlocklist.__table__.delete().where(TokenBlocklist.created < forty_days_ago)
    db.session.execute(query)
    db.session.commit()
    print('old tokens deleted')

remove_old_tokens()
```

Comment: The actual import error could be solved by modifying `sys.path` and using an absolute import. But there may be more problems.

Comment: Thank you for the fast comment. I'm researching sys.path and absolute imports now.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I was able to resolve the original error with absolute imports. Thank you. You were correct in that there may be more problems. Now I'm working with a remaining circular import issue (question updated).

Comment: I was able to get this working and will post one solution momentarily. Now I'm curious if I can run this without creating a flask app.

Comment: A working solution has been posted. However, if there was a way I could run this query without involving Flask, I would accept that as the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @michael-butscher's comment, I was able to resolve the import error with an altered script that makes use of absolute imports. After that, I broke out the app's use of the database so that both the main Flask app and this script could use the models.

⚠️ If there was a way I could run this query without involving Flask, I would accept that as a better answer.

new: database.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

models.py

```
...
from .database import db
...
```

app.py

```
...
from app.database import db
...
db.init_app(app)
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

remove_old_tokens.py

```
from flask import Flask
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../../'))
from app.database import db
from app.models import TokenBlocklist


def remove_old_tokens():
    forty_days = timedelta(days=40)
    forty_days_ago = datetime.now() - forty_days
    query = TokenBlocklist.__table__.delete().where(
        TokenBlocklist.created_at < forty_days_ago
    )
    db.session.execute(query)
    db.session.commit()
    print('old tokens deleted')


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' \
    + os.path.abspath('../../instance/db.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db.init_app(app)
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
    remove_old_tokens()
```