# apscheduler in Flask executes twice

Tags: python, flask, apscheduler

I have problem when i am using apscheduler in my flask application.

In my view.py file i am writing like this

```
import time
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

def test_scheduler():
     print "TEST"
     print time.time()


sched = Scheduler()
sched.add_interval_job(test_scheduler, seconds=5)
sched.start()
```

And then this method test_scheduler() executes twice in every five second

TEST
  1360844314.01
  TEST
  1360844314.2

Comment: Please have a look here, had the same issue in Django. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27303834/573034

Comment: This is absolutely crazy.  I am debugging some problems for two weeks and only few minutes ago I realised it was scheduler running twice!  And Google directed me immediately here.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I've made it,  I added in add_interval_job parameter to start after a certain time point

```
sched.add_interval_job(test_scheduler, seconds=5, start_date='2013-02-13 00:00')
```

Comment: Maybe this solves your problem but your question is completely unrelated to this answer

Answer (score 86):

In debug mode, Flask's reloader will load the flask app twice ([How to stop Flask from initialising twice in Debug Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449101/how-to-stop-flask-from-initialising-twice-in-debug-mode)). I'm not sure why this is, but it causes apscheduler's jobs to be scheduled twice. A quick `print "loaded scheduler"` right before `sched.start()` confirms this.

There are a couple ways around this, as mentioned in the linked answer. The one I found that worked best is just to disable the reloader like so:

```
app.run(use_reloader=False)
```

It means I have to reload my app manually as I develop it, but it's a small price to pay to get apscheduler working.

Comment: Excellent, just the answer I needed inbound from Google.  OP should accept.

Comment: This answer worked for me too and is the right answer factually. Could you please accept this?

Comment: is there no way to catch the restart signal/event. Its very bad to lose this feature only for using a scheduling lib.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25519547/8608146 is better, no need to compromise on reloading.

Answer (score 57):

When using the reloader, there are the master and child processes. Your scheduler thread runs in both. You need to prevent the scheduler from running in the master process

```py
if not app.debug or os.environ.get('WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN') == 'true':
  sched = Scheduler()
  sched.add_interval_job(test_scheduler, seconds=5)
  sched.start()
```

Comment: Yes, this helps. I tried out a lot of options, including flocked file without succeeding.

Comment: This does not work for me, because `app.debug` returns `False` even when Flask is in debug mode, i.e. `app.run(host='0.'0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)`

Comment: It seems that the problem is that `app.run` should be the last command, and before you run `app.run` you cannot know the state of Flask.

Comment: How would this work in django?

Comment: @Pygmalion have a config variable `MY_DEBUG=True` somewhere and use it in both places i.e. `app.run(debug=MY_DEBUG)` and `if not MY_DEBUG or ...` Also there's this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449101/how-to-stop-flask-from-initialising-twice-in-debug-mode#comment109713142_9476701)

Comment: You can set `DEBUG = True` as a Config object. In this case the `app` object knows the status before `app.run()` Worked for me like a charm.

Comment: Can totally agree with @MichaelLossagk . So far no complications for me at all

Comment: make sure that you run the flask app in debug mode. You can temporarily enable this by running this command `export FLASK_DEBUG=1`. This is applicable for your current terminal only.

Answer (score 19):

You can start the scheduler in Flask's [`before_first_request()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request) decorator, which "*registers a function to be run before the first request to this instance of the application*".

```
import time
import atexit

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


def print_date_time():
    print(time.strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p"))


@app.before_first_request
def init_scheduler():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(func=print_date_time, trigger="interval", seconds=3)
    scheduler.start()
    # Shut down the scheduler when exiting the app
    atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())
```

Note that `before_first_request()` will always be called again with the first request after server reload.

Comment: You can use this solution along with https://networklore.com/start-task-with-flask/ to have the before_first_requested triggered with starting the server

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: Unfortunately the decorator before_first_request has been deprecated :(

Answer (score -2):

the best solution is to use `add_cron_job('*')` instead of `add_interval_job('*')`