# Would starting APScheduler in a uwsgi app end up with one scheduler for each worker?

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, worker, apscheduler

I have a flask application in which I need the scheduling feature of APScheduler. The question is:

Where do I start the scheduler instance?

I use uwsgi+nginx to serve this application with multiple workers, wouldn't I end up with multiple instances of Scheduler that would be oblivious of each other? If this is correct, a single job would be triggered multiple times, wouldn't it?

What is the best strategy in this case so I end up with just one Scheduler instance and still be able to access the application's context from within the scheduled jobs?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053364/what-would-be-the-best-way-to-make-sure-only-one-worker-launches-the-apscheduler) has the same problem albeit with gunicorn instead of uwsgi, but the answer could be similar.

Below is the code defining "app" as a uwsgi callable application object.
The file containing this code is called wsgi.py (not that it matters).

```
app = create_app(config=ProductionConfig())

def job_listener(event):
    get_ = "msg from job '%s'" % (event.job)
    logging.info(get_)

# This code below never gets invoked when I check with worker_id() == 1
# The only time it is run is with worker_id() value of 0
app.sched = Scheduler()
app.sched.add_jobstore(ShelveJobStore('/tmp/apsched_%d' % uwsgi.worker_id()), 'file')
app.sched.add_listener(job_listener,
                   events.EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED |
                   events.EVENT_JOB_MISSED |
                   events.EVENT_JOB_ERROR)
app.sched.start()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

uWSGI has a feature called mules (see: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Mules.html), you can use them to start a script under the master which is not accessible via socket. It's designed to offload a work from the main app using schedulers and for signal handling so it seems to be perfect for deploying a scheduler inside the uwsgi stack.

Answer (score 1):

UWSGI has a function uwsgi.worker_id(). If you start the scheduler conditionally in a specific worker, you won't end up with multiple scheduler instances.

Comment: I assume the worker_id is assigned as they are created. How can I know beforehand which id I need to qualify with to start the scheduler?

Comment: I don't know how they are assigned. If they are assigned sequentially, you could just use worker id 0 or 1 (whichever is the first).

Comment: It seems like they're indeed assigned sequentially, starting from 1.

Comment: The real question is, if worker 1 is killed, will it respawn with the same ID?

Comment: My research says that yes, they will reuse the IDs.

Comment: Alex, thanks for your research. I will try this, if it works, I will accept your answer.

Comment: It turns out that the worker_id() returns 0 for the first thread, and the Scheduler is instantiated. From looking at the uwsgi application log, 2 workers were created, and when they do, somehow the scheduler is not created multiple times.  But when one of these workers schedule a job, it never gets executed when the time comes.

Comment: Worker ID 0 is only returned for the "master" process. You want to add the jobs and start the scheduler in worker #1. If that doesn't work, look at the (debug) log and see what the scheduler is doing.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything special about whether I start the scheduler in worker #1 vs #0. I turned on the debug and the debugger only spits out info when the uwsgi server is restarted, it almost seems like the Scheduler thread is halted after running for just a few seconds.

Comment: IIRC uwsgi disables Python threads by default. Have you tried with --enable-threads?

Comment: Yes, --enable-threads are in the config, and it is reflected in the log that python threads are enabled.  This is really puzzling.

Comment: The UWSGI docs say that if worker_id() returns 0, it means the current process is not a worker at all. That's why you should check against worker id == 1. Did you try that? If it didn't work, could you add the code you used to initialize the webapp and the scheduler?

Comment: I did check for worker_id() == 1. But the code never gets called with that value.  I added the code in the post above.