# Gunicorn --workers 3 --preload

Tags: django, gunicorn, apscheduler

We are running a django web application via Gunicorn + NGNIX (on a linux server). We find that the jobs we are executing via APScheduler are being executed 3 times each (which is undesirable). We solved the problem on our local computers, however, the problem remains when being run via Gunicorn.

This was the most informative thread:
[Make sure only one worker launches the apscheduler event in a pyramid web app running multiple workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053364/make-sure-only-one-worker-launches-the-apscheduler-event-in-a-pyramid-web-app-ru/40162246#40162246)

Our problem is that we want to execute the following code: `env/bin/gunicorn module_containing_app:app -b 0.0.0.0:8080 --workers 3 --preload`, we are unsure about two things:

- We have a domain "`example.com`", should this be taken into consideration?
- We are trying to find the `env/bin/gunicorn` folder/path with no luck. We are also trying to understand what to replace `module_containing_app:app` with because of this.

Comment: Could be because of 3 workers. Each workers creates an instance of your Django project. Changing it to 1 might solve your problem.