# How can I execute a function when Flask app ends?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, flask, web-deployment

I am building a Flask app and was wondering how can I tell it to do a function when the user clicks "Ctrl + C or X" basically when they end the application. For this example, let's say I just want it to open a file and write "done" to it. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850261/doing-something-before-program-exit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doing something before program exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850261/doing-something-before-program-exit)

Answer (score 2):

The way the program is terminated is through signals sent by your system. Two examples of signals are `SIGKILL` which corresponds to `kill -9` and `SIGINT` which corresponds to pressing `ctrl + c`.

You have a built-in library in Python called [`signals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) though which you could play around with signals in Unix/Linux.

Simply import the library using `import signals` and then write a simple callback function that runs whenever the registered signal is received.

Example of signal handler function:

```
def receiveSignal(signalNumber, frame):
print('Received:', signalNumber)
return
```

Example of registering signals

```
signal.signal(signal. SIGKILL, receiveSignal)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, receiveSignal)
```

Now, whenever your program received the registered signals, the `receiveSignal` function is called and you could handle the task of writing to the file and then exiting over there.

The example above is taken from StackAbuse and you could find the complete example [here](https://stackabuse.com/handling-unix-signals-in-python/)

Comment: This code will not pass as you are not allowed to handle `signal.SIGKILL` or `signal.SIGSTOP`. SIGTERM or SIGINT is ok.

Answer (score -2):

Use atexit to handle this, from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30739397/5782985, I have test on my code,  it worked.

```py
import atexit

#defining function to run on shutdown
def close_running_threads():
    for thread in the_threads:
        thread.join()
    print "Threads complete, ready to finish"

#Register the function to be called on exit
atexit.register(close_running_threads)

#start your process
app.run()
```

Comment: From the [atexit documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html): "The functions registered via this module are not called when the program is killed by a signal not handled by Python, when a Python fatal internal error is detected, or when `os._exit()` is called."

Comment: atexit is not called when you use Ctrl+C

Comment: To expand on @J.T's point, this won't be called when your program receives `SIGTERM` unless your program also handles `SIGTERM` in a signal handler - in which case you might just as well do your cleanup in the signal handler.