# Python Dash timer?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am building a web application that grabs data from SQL server every day.
I have been using the Interval component so far. 
However, this time I want to get data at the point when I want. For example, 3 pm and 7 pm. Is there a way of setting a certain update time instead of giving an interval?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could schedule the grab using the underlying Flask server as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214270/scheduling-a-function-to-run-every-hour-on-flask). However, you would still need the `Interval` component to update the UI.