# Run python script in an range of hours

Tags: python, heroku, telegram, telepot

can i run my script in an range of hours?
For example: I would like to execute my script every day from 6am to 12 pm. At 12:01 pm i would like to kill the process

Thanks

PS: My script is hosted on heroku

Comment: please add the link to your script or include the code ^^

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: running from windows/linux?

Comment: Yes, you can run/end a python script via another python script that shouldn't be closed throughout the process.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR ; use cron in linux- make your python script executable then config your cron to run how ever you want.

In windows you can use a scheduled task.

Abit of explanation about `cron`- It's basically a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems.

Follow the link below for full explanation on how to run python scripts with crons.

https://medium.com/@gavinwiener/how-to-schedule-a-python-script-cron-job-dea6cbf69f4e

Alternatively if the heroku is running all the time you can use 
`BackgroundScheduler()` from `APScheduler`

reference -[Scheduling a function to run every hour on Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214270/scheduling-a-function-to-run-every-hour-on-flask)