# How to send automated reminder emails in specific intervals in Python flask

Tags: python, email, flask

I am quite new in Flask. I am stuck with a specific issue.

I have a requirement where I need to send automated reminder emails at specific intervals. Let's say, every 10 days an automated reminder will be sent to the users who did not fill up a survey form.

How can I achieve this in python flask?

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: You could create a [Flask-Script](https://flask-script.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and run it via cron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [flask mail](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/) a flask extension that does exactly what you need.
You can send an email every X seconds and when he verified it it would stop sending the email. I'd suggest a simple boolean. If you want you can use [BackgroundScheduler()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214270/scheduling-a-function-to-run-every-hour-on-flask). In order to send it every x seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the tips...it worked..one more question i am using blockingscheduler and my code looks like this `sched = BlockingScheduler()

sched.add_job(job_function, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=9, minute=13, end_date='2020-06-05 09:14:00')

sched.start()` how will i end the scheduler as, it is not getting stopped after the mentioned end date..