# Check if there are no requests processed for last n mins

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have a flask Rest api running as a docker container. I need to check in flask api if there are no requests processed for last 5 mins, then I need to log a message saying there are no new requests for last 5 mins.
I can keep logging a message every 5 mins and is mentioned in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214270/how-to-schedule-a-function-to-run-every-hour-on-flask/38501429#38501429).
But what am looking for is to log a message when there are no  new requests for last 5 mins.
If anyone has achieved this, then please suggest how ?