# web service for automate script

Tags: python, database, web-services, visualization

Not sure if this is type of question is for this forum but I can´t figure out any better place to ask.
I have a python script fetching data. I would like to:

- Run the script on daily basis, automated
- Store the data to a database
- calculate KPIs and re-structure the data
- Visualize the data on a website (PowerBI or similar)

I know that I can make my own computer a server, but I would prefer a web service. Which webservices are there good for small hobby projects?

regards

Comment: may be go for flask. see these links  for more info [job scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214270/how-to-schedule-a-function-to-run-every-hour-on-flask) [viz1](https://towardsdatascience.com/web-visualization-with-plotly-and-flask-3660abf9c946) & [viz2](https://towardsdatascience.com/https-medium-com-radecicdario-next-level-data-visualization-dashboard-app-with-bokeh-flask-c588c9398f98) [data transform](https://sarahleejane.github.io/learning/python/2015/08/09/simple-tables-in-webapps-using-flask-and-pandas-with-python.html)

Comment: Thanks gowridev, but this requires me to have it on my own computer/service I assume?

Comment: Yes, you can host the services on your local machine or dedicated server. Flask is a web framework in python.