# Return an image taken from an URL without storing the image file

Tags: python, rest, flask

I have an endpoint which downloads an image from an URL, stores it in the project directory and returns the image on the web page.
But I don't want the image to be stored in my project directory. is there a way?
if not, is there a way to remove the image after the method is executed?

```
@app.route('/get_image', methods=['GET'])
def get_image():

    r = requests.get("Certain URL")
    file = open("sample.png", "wb")
    file.write(r.content)
    file.close()
    
    return send_file("sample.png", mimetype='image/gif')
```

Comment: One approach is to store the images in their own folder, and have a process that periodically cleans out the folder.  Alternatively, Flask's `send_file` will accept a file object, so you could use an `io.BytesIO` object to store the contents and pass that to `send_file`.  The object will get cleaned up by Python.

Comment: this problem was many times on Stackoverflow - for different files.

Comment: you shouldn't send `.png` as `'image/gif'` but as `'image/png'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @TimRoberts said in comment you would have to use `io.BytesIO` to create file-like object in memory, write in this file and later read from this file.

```
    r = requests.get("https://placekitten.com/640/360")

    file_like_object = io.BytesIO()
    file_like_object.write(r.content)
    file_like_object.seek(0)  # move to the beginning of file 

    return send_file(file_like_object, mimetype='image/png')
```

or shorter

```
    r = requests.get("https://placekitten.com/640/360")

    file_like_object = io.BytesIO(r.content)

    return send_file(file_like_object, mimetype='image/png')
```

And this can be usefull if you want to generate files instead of getting from server - ie. `plot` with `matplotlib`, `image` with `pillow`, `audio` from some `TextToSpeech API`, etc.

You could find many examples on Stackoverflow.

---

But if you don't want to edit file then there is even simpler method.

Using `requests.get(..., stream=True)` you may get `r.raw` which is `file-like` object.

```
    r = requests.get("https://placekitten.com/640/360", stream=True)

    file_like_object = r.raw

    return send_file(file_like_object, mimetype='image/png')
```

---

Minimal working code with both versions, and with real URL so everyone can copy and run it:

**EDIT:** I added example which resize image without saving on disk.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, send_file
import requests
import io
from PIL import Image

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
<img src="/get_image">get_image<br/>
<img src="/get_image_bytesio">get_image_bytesio<br/>
<img src="/get_image_bytesio_smaller">get_image_bytesio_smaller<br/>
''')

@app.route('/get_image')
def get_image():
    r = requests.get("https://placekitten.com/640/360", stream=True)  # it needs `stream=True`
    
    file_like_object = r.raw
    
    return send_file(file_like_object, mimetype='image/png')

@app.route('/get_image_bytesio')
def get_image_bytesio():
    r = requests.get("https://placebear.com/640/360")
    
    #file_like_object = io.BytesIO()
    #file_like_object.write(r.content)
    #file_like_object.seek(0)  # move to the beginning of file after writing

    file_like_object = io.BytesIO(r.content)

    return send_file(file_like_object, mimetype='image/png')

@app.route('/get_image_bytesio_smaller')
def get_image_bytesio_smaller():
    r = requests.get("https://placebear.com/640/360")
    
    file_like_object = io.BytesIO(r.content)

    # edit image without saving on disk    
    img = Image.open(file_like_object)
    img = img.resize((320, 180))

    # `seek()` has to be after `resize()` because it may use `lazy loading`
    
    file_like_object.seek(0)  # move to the beginning of file after reading
    img.save(file_like_object, 'PNG')
    
    file_like_object.seek(0)  # move to the beginning of file after writing
    
    return send_file(file_like_object, mimetype='image/png')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True 
    app.run()
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you can't send something without having it on your system. You can pass on the reference/link, but you can't make the server that's hosting it send it for you.

So your best bet is to delete it.

```
import os
if os.path.exists("theimage.img"):
  os.remove("theimage.img")
else:
  print("The file does not exist")
```

Now, you could do this as a separate view: create a Delete method view, send the request with the filename from a hidden form on your page. But that could get really messy (i.e. the timing on that might workout that you're deleting the file before you're done sending it).

I think you maybe want to store the images in a specific folder, and delete all of the images in that folder on a certain interval.

Here is a [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214270/how-to-schedule-a-function-to-run-every-hour-on-flask) on how to implement an app scheduler.
But that may even be more than you need. What you're looking to schedule is a fairly simple task.

[Cron](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-using-python--cms-28231) is a system process that can schedule tasks for you. It's pretty straightforward.

[Crontab](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/) is the python friendly version.