# How do I call a function every 24 hours in Python? I'm currently using Threading to run a Flask server and the function at the same time

Tags: python, flask, scheduled-tasks, python-multithreading

Right now, I'm trying to make a graphing website that tracks the progress (XP) of Discord users with a bot called MEE6, here is my [repl](https://replit.com/@StarkOdinson/gwaff20#main.py). Right now, I'm using Threading to create two separate threads - one for a web server, and one containing a while loop with the function inside:

```
def func():
    while True:
        backend.get_details()
        time.sleep(86400)
```

This should make the function run every 24 hours, but as evidenced by the time stamps in the database:

```
  "05-November-2021 00:02:58": 2106855,
  "05-November-2021 00:52:48": 2106855,
  "05-November-2021 01:23:21": 2106855,
  "05-November-2021 03:48:13": 2106874,
  "05-November-2021 07:13:40": 2106874
```

It is not. How can I fix this?

Here is my threading code:

```
def keep_alive():
server = Thread(target=run)
data = Thread(target=func)
server.start()
data.start()

def run():
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # s.run()
    # os.system('cls')
    keep_alive()
    # print('i')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried fixing it using the `schedule` package? For an example see this post:

[Python script to do something at the same time every day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088037/python-script-to-do-something-at-the-same-time-every-day)

For running a scheduler in the background (i.e. while running an app) see this excellent post:

[How to schedule a function to run every hour on Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214270/how-to-schedule-a-function-to-run-every-hour-on-flask)

Comment: I did see that post earlier, but I didn't really know how to make it work with the threading as I'm quite new to this. Where should I put the `schedule.every().day.at("01:00").do(job,'It is 01:00')` and the while loop?

I'd also appreciate if you could tell me what the `time.sleep` is there for since the scheduling is handled by the scheduler

Comment: I've implemented the schedule as per the post you linked, however, the function is not being called (I set it to print a number for every iteration in the for loop and there is no output in the console). Could you take a look?

Comment: The `schedule.run_pending()` method runs all tasks that should be run at that point. The method is fairly simple:
https://github.com/dbader/schedule/blob/master/schedule/__init__.py

Hence, the `time.sleep` still serves as passing time.

Comment: I also noticed another post which handles running a scheduler when running an app which explains it very well:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214270/how-to-schedule-a-function-to-run-every-hour-on-flask

I will add it to the answer.