# SQLAlchemy queries in a function scheduled to run every hour on Flask using APScheduler

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

For my flask app I have a folder called 'flaskblog'.
In the same directory I have run.py:

```
from flaskblog import app, db

db.init_app(app)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

Inside flaskblog folder init.py:

```
#...some more code
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
#.. and so on

def register_app(app):
    """Create an application."""
    main_blueprint = Blueprint('main', __name__)
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
    return app

register_app(app)

# import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
# define the job
from flaskblog.models import Chatmessage
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def hello_job():
    today = datetime.today()
    start_date = today - timedelta(days=1)
    end_date = today + timedelta(days=1)
    messages = Chatmessage.query.filter(Chatmessage.date_sent <= end_date).\
        filter(Chatmessage.date_sent >= start_date).all()
    
    print(today, start_date, end_date)
    print('Hello Job! The time is: ')
# init BackgroundScheduler job
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
# in your case you could change seconds to hours
scheduler.add_job(hello_job, trigger='interval', seconds=10)
scheduler.start()
#find correct place to put job starts
```

I am trying to schedule a function to run every now and then like explained in this question:
[How to schedule a function to run every hour on Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214270/how-to-schedule-a-function-to-run-every-hour-on-flask)

The problem is that I want to use models, Flask-SQLAlchemy.. like Model.query... but it cannot be used before applications is registered "register_app(app)" because of circular imports. So I put schedule after comment "#import BackgroundScheduler" in my code.

Is it a correct way to do it? I get the doubt from reloading visual code debugger and seeing that function hello_job() from last reload is still running, or if app fails to load function hello_job() starts to run anyways. So am afraid it could have issues on production server.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

in your init.py

```
...
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.start()
atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())

...
#at the end    
import job
```

in a job.py

```
from init import scheduler

cron_time = '0 * * * *'

@scheduler.scheduled_job(CronTrigger.from_crontab(cron_time), id='hello_job')
def hello_job():
   ...
```