# How to stop flask from reloading the code twice?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug, apscheduler

The question was asked, but I have another issue.

I've tried:

```
app.run(use_reloader=False)
```

As in:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from scheduler import *
from regions import regions

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", regions=regions)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(use_debugger=False, use_reloader=False)
```

But nothing happens. It just keeps on reloading.

```
~/workspace/finalproject/weather/ $ flask run
* Serving Flask app "sync"
* Forcing debug mode off
* Running on http://ide50-artemnikitin27ed.cs50.io:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
* Restarting with stat
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Scheduler started
DEBUG:apscheduler.scheduler:Looking for jobs to run
DEBUG:apscheduler.scheduler:No jobs; waiting until a job is added
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Scheduler started
DEBUG:apscheduler.scheduler:Looking for jobs to run
DEBUG:apscheduler.scheduler:No jobs; waiting until a job is added
```

I've even turned off the debug mode, but still the reloader keeps running the code twice at startup.

I need this in order to stop the Apscheduler running twice, which works perfectly, expect for this issue.

I'll be very grateful for any help!

**SOLUTION:**

For disabling the reloader, if you use `flask run` execute `flask run --no-reload` instead as in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25504196/8882620

For solving the problem without blocking the reloader, place the apscheduler settings in a function and wrap it with `@app.before_first_request`:

```
@app.before_first_request
def before_first_request():
   scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
   scheduler.start()
   scheduler.add_job(
   func=historical,
   trigger=CronTrigger(hour=12, minute=12),
      id='save_weather',
      name='Archive avg temp for current day',
      replace_existing=True)

   # Shut down the scheduler when exiting the app
   atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())
```

Comment: Have you seen this topic : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874782/apscheduler-in-flask-executes-twice 
?

Comment: Wow! And how to pass that argument to flask run?

Comment: I've found `flask run --no-reload` to solve the problem, thanks!

Comment: I agree. It works with the @app.before_first_request decorator (I've updated the question).