# Schedule jobs dynamically with Flask APScheduler

Tags: python-3.x, flask, apscheduler

I'm trying the code given at  [advanced.py](https://github.com/viniciuschiele/flask-apscheduler/blob/master/examples/advanced.py) with the following modification for adding new jobs.

I created a route for adding a new job

```
@app.route('/add', methods = ['POST'])
def add_to_schedule():
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data)

    d = {
        'id': 'job'+str(random.randint(0, 100)),
        'func': 'flask_aps_code:job1',
        'args': (random.randint(200,300),random.randint(200, 300)),
        'trigger': 'interval',
        'seconds': 10

    }
    print(app.config['JOBS'])
    scheduler.add_job(id = 'job'+str(random.randint(0, 100)), func = job1)
    #app.config.from_object(app.config['JOBS'].append(d))
    return str(app.config['JOBS']), 200
```

I tried adding the jobs to config['JOBS'] as well as scheduler.add_job. But none of my new jobs are not getting executed. Additionally, my first scheduled job doesnt get executed till I do a ctrl+c on the terminal, after which the first [scheduled job seems to execute](https://github.com/viniciuschiele/flask-apscheduler/blob/master/examples/advanced.py#L9), twice. What am I missing?

Edit: Seemingly the job running twice is because of [flask reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874782/apscheduler-in-flask-executes-twice), so ignore that.