# Stop local development server in Eclipse(Pydev) like ASP .Net Developement Server

Tags: python, eclipse, flask, pydev

I am running a Flask-Python script from eclipse. When i run a script it's running with the development server url : `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`. When i click `Terminate` or `Terminate All (Ctrl + Alt + F9)` from eclipse, it's terminate/stop the process. But, If i access the url : `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` from browser, i can access this url. How do i stop this permanently.

Like, if we are using ASP .Net projects, we can access the url after stopped debugging from visual studio. Completely stop debugging for ASP .Net projects, need to stop the local `ASP .Net Developement Server`. How do i achieve like this in eclipse.

Note : I checked this scenario with Django projects from eclipse. But i'm facing the same issue.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

The usual issue is that you have a main script which executes a secondary process to do the work (for auto-reload).

I haven't checked this, but the usual 'easy-fix' is passing in the command line an option which says that you don't want the reload to happen (in which case it wouldn't create a second process).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem, so i created [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430718/terminating-flasks-internal-server-in-eclipse-aptana-pydev/29431209#29431209).

Eventually i found solution after reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449101/how-to-stop-flask-from-initialising-twice-in-debug-mode).

Trick is while running your application pass use_reloader=False.

```
app.run("0.0.0.0", 5051, debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```