# Python program seems to be running twice

Tags: python, flask

I have a python program which is running Flask. I noticed a strange thing, it looks like the program is running twice, which I do not want.

Here is the file for starting the program(runserver.py, in the root folder /):

```
from myapp import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "woho"
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

When running this, I can see two "woho" in the terminal, indicating that something is strange.

in the folder /myapp I have __init__.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__) 

import myapp.views
```

and then in my views.py (also in /myapp) I have all the views like:

```
from myapp import app
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's due to the reloader of flask/werkzeug, which reloads automatically when you change the code.

so give debug=False if you don't want/need that, e.g. for "production".

[How to stop Flask from initialising twice in Debug Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449101/how-to-stop-flask-from-initialising-twice-in-debug-mode)

Comment: This solved the problem! Although I think it's strange that it restarts directly after the first start...

Comment: that's required for the reloader - how else should it be able to restart itself?