# Flask plus Schedule

Tags: python, flask, python-multithreading, schedule

Hi I want to integrate [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) with my Flask app since I would need to do some routinely tasks. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27149386/issue-when-running-schedule-with-flask) that he used threading to run it on the background. However when I tried it on mine, I cannot exit my app using Ctrl-C, I am using Windows. I will soon deploy it on Heroku, what's wrong?

Also is there any better and 'human-friendly' like schedule to do some routine task for Flask? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from datetime import datetime
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import schedule
import time
from threading import Thread


app = Flask(__name__)

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

def run_schedule():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    schedule.every(5).seconds.do(job)
    sched_thread = Thread(target=run_schedule)
    sched_thread.start()
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [APScheduler](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/#storing-data). It supports background scheduler.

Here's sample code I used flask with apscheduler.

```
from flask import Flask
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor

app = Flask(__name__)

executors = {
    'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(16),
    'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(4)
}

sched = BackgroundScheduler(timezone='Asia/Seoul', executors=executors)

def job():
    print('hi')

sched.add_job(job, 'interval', seconds=5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sched.start()
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Comment: Should I just .add_job to have 2 jobs right? Thanks!

Comment: I tried the same, my flask application is running fine. But the added function ran only once! It didn't run again after the set interval. Can someone explain the possible error?