# How to call a python background Job along with application startup

Tags: python, background, schedule

I would like to launch a background schedule job to run daily once along with application `start(app.run())`

Could someone help

Comment: We need more specifics about your program and your intentions.

Comment: From my python Flask application, i would like to schedule a background Job that runs daily once at a specific time to sync few set of data from another server. I am planning to use schedule library for to schedule the data sync job. I was thinking to launch the schedule along with application start up itself. Please suggest better way of doing this

Comment: @JyothiAbraham Use `BackgroundScheduler` of [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/schedulers/background.html#apscheduler.schedulers.background.BackgroundScheduler), for implementation with Flask this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52068807/8840245